# OpenVPN: IP check looks good but doesn't seem right

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN with a new VPN service (used to use PTPP without an issue). I am deeply suspicious that the VPN is not working though. The IP checks seem to indicate that everything is ok, but when I try to connect to a site that is blocked in my country I am redirected to the usual government website. I'm assuming not all traffic is going through the VPN. How can I check things are secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when an OpenVPN client is active, only network traffic to and from the OpenVPN server site will pass over the VPN. General web browsing, for example, will be accomplished with direct connections that bypass the VPN.

Add the following directive to the server configuration file:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

If your VPN setup is over a wireless network, where all clients and the server are on the same wireless subnet, add the local flag:

```
push "redirect-gateway local def1"
```

Pushing the redirect-gateway option to clients will cause all IP network traffic originating on client machines to pass through the OpenVPN server. The server will need to be configured to deal with this traffic somehow, such as by NATing it to the internet, or routing it through the server site's HTTP proxy.

On Linux, you could use a command such as this to NAT the VPN client traffic to the internet:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This command assumes that the VPN subnet is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy (taken from the server directive in the OpenVPN server configuration) and that the local ethernet interface is eth0.

When redirect-gateway is used, OpenVPN clients will route DNS queries through the VPN, and the VPN server will need handle them. This can be accomplished by pushing a DNS server address to connecting clients which will replace their normal DNS server settings during the time that the VPN is active. For example:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz"
```

Comment: One question, where is the server configuration file. Been Googleing but can't find anything clear on it.

Comment: You have detailed explanation [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/457103-install-and-configure-openvpn-server-on-linux) The first step is to copy a sample configuration file to work with. This is done with the command sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz /etc/openvpn/. Now decompress the server.conf.gz file with the command sudo gzip -d /etc/openvpn/server.conf.gz. The configuration options to edit are in this file. Open server.conf up in a text editor